# Powershell GetChildItem using wrong path to find match

Tags: powershell, file, directory

right now I am trying to code a little Powershell script to check if a file exists.
One of my variables is called test and it's point is to find files in the basepath which are no older than a day

The files are named in the logic: File2021-02-1717821 and so on

my code right now:

```
$basepath='C:\Users\MyName\Documents\2020-09-06 193009 Testing'

$date=(get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("YYYY-MM-dd")

$test=Get-ChildItem $basepath | Where-Object Name -match ($date)  | ForEach-Object {$_.FullName}
```

But Test will just return the files of the script location rather than the files of the basepath variable. I also have a variable to return the latest file that matches the test criteria but it also returns the script itself rather than looking in the directory of basepath.

```
$last = Get-ChildItem -Path $test | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

Comment: [1] is $basepath actually pointing to a folder in which the files are? [2] `ToString("YYYY-MM-dd")` --> `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` [3] add switch `-File` to `Get-ChildItem` in order to list only file objects, not folders too

Comment: thanks i will try this tomorrow and let you know how it went

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
($basepath = 'D:\Temp\DateStringFiles')
# Results
<#
D:\Temp\DateStringFiles
#>

($date     = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))
# Results
<#
2021-02-16
#>

Get-ChildItem -Path $basepath | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp\DateStringFiles


Mode          LastWriteTime Length Name                   
----          ------------- ------ ----                   
-a----  17-Feb-21     09:07      0 File2021-02-1617821.txt
-a----  17-Feb-21     09:07      0 File2021-02-1617822.txt
-a----  17-Feb-21     09:07      0 File2021-02-1717821.txt
#>


(
$test     = Get-ChildItem -Path $basepath | 
            Where-Object -Property FullName -Match $Date | 
            Format-Table -AutoSize

)
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp\DateStringFiles


Mode          LastWriteTime Length Name                   
----          ------------- ------ ----                   
-a----  17-Feb-21     09:07      0 File2021-02-1617821.txt
-a----  17-Feb-21     09:07      0 File2021-02-1617822.txt
#>

(
$last     = Get-ChildItem -Path $basepath | 
            Where-Object -Property FullName -Match $Date | 
            Select-Object -First 1 | 
            Format-Table -AutoSize
)
# Results
<#
    Directory: D:\Temp\DateStringFiles


Mode          LastWriteTime Length Name                   
----          ------------- ------ ----                   
-a----  17-Feb-21     09:07      0 File2021-02-1617821.txt
#>
```

Comment: thanks your code helped me solve it, my mistake was that I wrote "match" instead of "Match" in the $test variable. now it works just fine :)